# Arduino + Web Service

Tags: arduino-mega, android, web-service

I am doing my CBT, and i need help...
I need a Webservice in C#, and it will send commands to my Arduino( Mega 2560 + Ehternet Shield )...
My Webservice will recibe commands from Android and Web

[image]

**EDIT**

I wanna know what kind of C# WebService Project I have to create...

[image]

Comment: What is your question exactly? If you want to know where to begin: google. Find some tutorials and do them to get familiar with all the different parts of the project. If you run into any troubles with those, maybe we can help you.

Comment: Go easy on this forum please. Dont be as strict as stackoverflow.com. Arduino does take a bit of time to learn. Tolerate basic questions please.

Comment: The question is probably better suited to another stack exchange forum. The question really isn't Arduino related, but more about web programming on a PC. Once you have that and it is ready to send commands to the Arduino, I hope you'll come back here with your Arduino questions. It sounds like a fun project.

Comment: @Siddharth it's not really our opinion that counts. If you'd like a change in policy, [propose it on meta](http://meta.arduino.stackexchange). However, this type of question wouldn't be allowed anywhere on SE because it would  be opinion based which often leads to bad content.

Comment: @JRobert this wouldn't be allowed on SO for sure. However, yes, we can help with specifics on the Arduino side....